# How can I open a db.sqlite3 file and have a look at its content?

Tags: sqlite

I don't know how to open a db.sqlite3 file in reader-friendly way.
I hope the data in it would be shown in tables

Comment: The [command line shell](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) or any of the many third-party programs for working with sqlite databases.

Comment: https://sqlitebrowser.org/ maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Upload your file here and get the tabulated result:
  http://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/
- OR run a Python script like below

```
def create_connection(db_file):
 """ create a database connection to the SQLite database specified by the db_file :param db_file: database file :return: Connection object or None """ conn = None
try: 
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file) except Error as e: 
    print(e) return conn

def select_all_tasks(conn): 
""" Query all rows in the tasks table :param conn: the Connection object :return: """
    cur = conn.cursor() 
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks")           rows = cur.fetchall() for row in rows: print(row)
```